# C check if fd is open using write(2)

Tags: c, file-descriptor, errno

Is possible to know with system call `write(2)` if the fd that I'm  sending data to is open or close?

My problem is that I'm writing to a fd that is sometimes closed and sometimes open. I think there must be a way to know with `write` this kind of situation but I can't find that.

Comment: `write(2)` has return values.

Comment: Why is your code attempting to write to an already closed file descriptor?  Unless this is a socket (where the connection was closed by the remote endpoint), then it speaks to a bug in your program if you have code that attempts to write to a handle may have been closed elsewhere in the program.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @selbie Socket does not get closed when connection was closed, so there are no exceptions.

Comment: "*My problem is that I'm writing to a fd that is sometimes closed and sometimes open.*" no, you have a problem with you program's design. Simply track the state of the fd.

Comment: @alk I doesn't have fd control because is in another process. So sometimes this process is alive sometimes not, and the system call write in my case is blocking because I think the fd's process is closed after process death. I really don't understand this kind of behaviour because like someone answer I'm expected return value -1 but it doesn't happen. I would like to know why.

Comment: How does your process receive the fd from the other process?

Comment: @soissy You cannot receive invalid fd from another process, fd does not get closed when some other process dies. There is a bug in your code. You _always_ have control over your fds.

Comment: @Ivan - Correct. I was trying to get the OP to speak to what his definition of "closed" meant. It maybe that the {socket, pipe, device driver} represented by the fd is valid and "open", but the remote thing it talks to may have gone away.  In any case, assuming the handle itself wasn't closed by the owning process, the only way to really know if the fd is valid is to just attempt read/write operations and judiciously check the return value for errors.

Comment: @alk my process receives fd from other process with select() and accept()

Comment: @Ivan I have control of my fd, I can't control fd of other process. I don't have control of client's fd, so when I try to write on this fd I can't know is valid or invalid(invalid for example because process client is dead).

Comment: @selbie you have the point, but my problem is that I don't have a return value of write() because I think the system call trying to write on fd, closed by client because client process dies, then write() block my process (in my opinion this kind of behaviour is strange because I think that in any case if write finds "bad fd" should return a "correct" value and also a errno must be setted but is not happen).

Comment: @soissy Your fd is always valid, regardless of whether client process died or not. If `write` is blocking you, then client process is not dead or there is another fd referring to the same object, probably _your_ process (server?). You probably forgot to close it after forking.

Comment: @Ivan I'm sure that client process where I must send data with `write` is dead. Yes, my process is server, and I think is improbable (maybe impossible) that my process has another refferring to the same fd because sometimes my program works. I don't use any `fork`.

Comment: @soissy You should check what fds your process has. Maybe examining `/proc/<pid>/fd/` can shed some light on this.

Comment: Which kind of file the blocking fd is referring to, please?

Comment: What exactly is the file from the other process?  A file on disk, a pipe, or something else?  Sounds like the "write" is blocking because there's no one reading the other side of the pipe.  You could do the ioclt/fcntl call to make it non-blocking and then intelligently handle such failures.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a system function that doesn't affect the file (if opened), instead of *write*, use *fstat* ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat))

```
int fstat(int fd, struct stat *buf);
```

Example

```
struct stat buf;
if (fstat(fd, &buf) == -1) {
    // fd is either closed or not accessible 
}
```

`fstat()` returns `-1` if it couldn't use the file descriptor (`0` otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write)

> On success, the number of bytes written is returned (zero indicates
>   nothing was written). On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set
>   appropriately.

So just check the return value for -1